# Remove a class if user is viewing website on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been having trouble trying to see if I can figure out how to create a function to remove the bg-parallax class from my webpage if user is on mobile. I've read through the link below which is on a similar topic but can't work out a solution. I'm not sure if this is even possible? Would appreciate any of your thoughts :)

[remove class if mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499539/remove-class-if-mobile)

```
<div id="home-cov" class="bg-parallax">
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).>>something?<<(function(){
  if($(this).>>isMobile?<< ) {
     $("home-cov").removeClass("bg-parallax");
     } else {
     $("home-cov").addClass("bg-parallax");
     }
 });  
});
```

Comment: why complicating ? change style using media query when on mobile

Comment: take a look to [this example](https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488)

Comment: I've got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you have is that you're missing the ID prefix of a hash (`#`) before your identifiers. From there it's just a matter of picking a mobile width at which you want to swap the classes. `768` is a fairly common breakpoint in the regard.

The following examples shows how you can toggle the `bg-parallax` class on resize, in addition to checking the width when the page is loaded:

```js
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) { 
    $("#home-cov").removeClass("bg-parallax");
  }
  else {
    $("#home-cov").addClass("bg-parallax");
  }
});
```

```css
.bg-parallax {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="home-cov">Sample</div>
```

Note, however, that this can be achieved **purely** through CSS, without any need for jQuery at all, by making use of [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Note that this time the rule will be applied to a minimum width of `769px`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  #home-cov {
    /* The .bg-parallax rules */
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="home-cov">Sample</div>
```

Click 'Run Code Snippet' and then 'Full Page' to see either approach in effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, I was totally over complicating it for myself!

Comment: You could make this simplier if you use `toggleClass('bg-parallax', $(window).width() <= 768)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on link you provided you should just define this as global variable

```
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;
```

then use it like

```
if(isMobile) {
    // this is mobile
    $("home-cov").removeClass("bg-parallax");
} else {
    $("home-cov").addClass("bg-parallax");
}
```

if you gonna go with $(window).width, I suggest to use css media queries

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px)  { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```